# Widget "Archive Posts" doesn't pull posts on the homepage

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, archive, elementor, posts

Good afternoon, everyone! I have a question regarding WordPress, and I would greatly appreciate it if someone could help me out.

Here's the situation: I created an archive in the Elementor Theme Builder for my blog posts. During the creation process, I used the Archive Posts widget, and it successfully displayed all the test posts I had made. However, when I use this widget (Archive Posts) on my homepage, it doesn't retrieve the blog posts. Instead, it pulls a version of my homepage in card format.

I appreciate any assistance you can provide!

I tried watching the tutorial on how the archive works, but it didn't work.